# How to replace .p-breadcrumb-chevron with full stop in Angular

Tags: primeng, breadcrumbs

[image: 1]

I am using Prime ng Breadcrumbs and I want to replace pi-chevron-right into black dot in Angular.

.I am new to Angular..Anyone please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following workaround using *Renderer2* :

1 - inject Renderer2 inside constructor of your component

```
    constructor(private _renderer2:Renderer2){}
```

2 - implements `AfterViewInIt` interface

3 - inside ngAfterViewInIt() do the following:

```
    ngAfterViewInit(){
       let li:HTMLCollectionOf<Element> = document.getElementsByClassName('p-breadcrumb-chevron');
       for(let i =0 ;i<li.length;i++){
           this._renderer2.removeClass(li[i],'pi-chevron-right')
          this._renderer2.addClass(li[i],'pi-circle-fill')

      }
    }
```

> it's a workaround but it works